# folder inside the same folder error

Tags: 14.04, directory

I have a remote machine, where due to some copying error, there is the same folder infinetely nested inside itself.

I am unable to delete it using `rm`, I don't root access to the remote machine.

Is there anyway we can mitigate this issue?

Remote and local machine are both 14.04.

Comment: Without write access you cannot delete or modify the problematic directory. ------ Could you please send `ls -ld` of it?

Comment: Question says they can't delete, self-answer says they fixed by deleting o.O

Answer (score 1):

Due to symbolic link failures, the directories got nested 48 levels deep. I started deleting at level six and then continued outwards.